# Hyperref package is causing error message

Tags: errors, hyperref, urls

I am trying to typeset my document, but the including the hyperref package gives me the following error:

> The required file
>   tex\latex\url\url.sty is missing.

Now my problem can probably be solved by installing the url package, but my question is: Why do I *have to* do this? There are no odd references in my document. I even tried using it like this

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    Hello
    \end{document}
```

and it still produced the same error message.

So why won't this work? Is the hyperref package useless without the url package?

Comment: Your TeX installation seems to be broken or incomplete!

Comment: @christianhupfer How can I confirm that it's indeed broken and if so: how do I fix it? Simply reinstall?

Comment: Did you check whether the `url.sty` is really not under the specified position? If it is there and it cannot be found nevertheless by the TeX system, it is perhaps broken (missing environment variables) On which OS do you use TeX and which distribution is there?

Comment: @christianhupfer I really wouldn't know where to look for the file url.sty. I am working on windows 7 and using miktex 2.9.

Comment: Search for `url.sty` using the OS `find a file` capabilities? I am sure, there is basically only one `url.sty` file on your computer ;-)

Comment: @chris It did not show any results for url.sty

Comment: I would reinstall Miktex 2.9 or use some kind of package adding utility (Is there such a thing with MikTeX?)

Comment: I'm using Miktex 2.9, maybe you have to change the settings. Check the option `Install packages on-the-fly`: If you need a new package installed you get asked to download it, then it's installed automatically, also it has a nice package-updater (which you have to start manually from time to time...)

Comment: @Aal: I am working on Linux, not on Windows, so I can provide limited help on MikTeX etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, links including URLs and their typesetting are an essential part of `hyperref`. Typesetting URLs does not need to be invented by `hyperef`, because package `url` already makes a good job. Therefore `hyperref` loads package `url` (and other packages) via `\RequirePackage`.

Of course, documents without any use of `\url` exists, thus a auto-load feature would be useful, but:

- A package cannot be loaded after `\begin{document}`.
- The first `\url` might be called in a group. All local definitions of the packages would be lost after the group (if package loading would be possible).
  Then at the next `\url`, the packages would have to be loaded again. But then
  the global resources are already present, possibly causing trouble.
- Package `hyperref` could note the usage of `\url` in the `.aux` file and load the package `url` in `\AtBeginDocument`. But:

  - There are packages that can/should not be loaded at this late time.
  - One more LaTeX run is needed, because the first run might be garbage
    because of the missing package `url`.

A clean solution would be, if the TeX distribution takes care of package dependencies and install the required packages automatically, if a package is installed. For example, TeX Live maintains some dependencies.
However, there are way too many packages to do this on a fine-granularity level.
Each package has to be inspected and analyzed. And this needs to be repeated at each update of the package.

But there are not any volunteers, which are willing to dig through thousands of packages *and* to do this on a regular basis for new package and updates.
And I do not see anyone, who is willing to pay for such a service.

AFAIK, there is just one person, who maintains MiKTeX, there is one person, who maintains the TeX Catalogue, there are a handful (at most) persons who maintain TeX Live and there are a handful (or less) persons that keep CTAN running.